# lstm prediction result delay phenomenon

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

Recently I'm using lstm to predict time series. I'm using keras 2.0 to construct my lstm model. It has a structure like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(timesteps, 1), return_sequences=False, stateful=False)
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I have tried to use this network to predict several time series including `sin(t)` and a real traffic flow dataset. I found that the prediction for sin is fine while the prediction for real dataset is just like shifting the last input value by one step. I don't know whether it's a prediction error or the network doesn't learn the pattern of the dataset at all. Does anyone get similar results? Are there any solutions to this annoying shift? Thanks a lot.
Here are some of my predictions:

[3 frequencies sin prediction result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1OFw.png)

[real traffic dataset prediction result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfTF3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply the starting point for your network and you'll have to work through it by trying various things.

To name only a few:

- Try different window lengths (timesteps fed into network)
- Try adding dense layers, or multiple LSTM layers, or fewer LTSM nodes
- Try different optimizers, with various learning rates
- Look for additional datapoints to feed into the network
- How much data do you have? You may need more to get a good prediction
- Try different offsets for the Y variable, how many timesteps do you need to be able to predict out for your specific problem?

The list goes on....

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It really helps me a lot. I googled this question for a long time but haven't got an explicit solution. I will try the strategies listed above. Wish to make some improvements. Thank you again!

Comment: @EricYu did you get the correct prediction results? If yes, can you please share the things you did to correct it? I am also getting similar results but I am still getting similar results only(delayed graph). I am trying to predict future data for a week from daily data from the past 1 year. Is this much data sufficient for predictions?